# Safari IOS video.play async blocked by user permission

Tags: ios, video, safari, media-player

I've an app that presents some assets, like image, video, audio to the user in a timeline.
I'm trying to find a way around the Safari "NotAllowedError: The play method is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context,".
The timeline is initiated by a user click on a 'start' button, so the user has interacted with the page. All other browsers work fine, but Safari prevents the playing of the video when some time later javascript code tries to call video.play().
I've tried making some 'interaction' with the video element on the initial click handler, like walking all 'video' elements and calling 'pause' method and it started working on MacOS Safari, but not on iPhone Safari.
Does anyone know how the error could be circumvented?